# How to run groupby in oracle on a table having Long as datatype for one of its column - illegal use of LONG datatype

Tags: oracle, constraints, listagg

```
SELECT ac.owner, ac.table_name, LISTAGG(column_name ,',' ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ac.constraint_name) AS "ABC" , ac.constraint_name, ac.constraint_type, ac.search_condition
        (SELECT ac2.table_name FROM all_cons_columns ac2 WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) fK_to_table, 
        (SELECT ac2.column_name FROM all_cons_columns ac2 WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) fK_to_column 
        FROM all_cons_columns acc, all_constraints ac WHERE     acc.constraint_name = ac.constraint_name AND acc.table_name = ac.table_name 
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'R', 'C', 'U') group by ac.owner, ac.table_name, ac.constraint_name, ac.constraint_type, ac.search_condition;
```

returns -

```
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have tried whats not. Any suggestions please?

Note - 1. Changing table data type is not an option.
       2. ac.search_condition seems to be of Long type
       3. Surely needs ac.search_condition in the query

Comment: One day Oracle will stop supporting `LONG` totally, what would you do then?

Comment: I can't wait. However, I think it will be a while, as Oracle will first have to re-engineer 244 data dictionary views (as of 12.1) without breaking any tools that rely on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a search_condition_vc column, try that instead, it is a varchar2

are any of your search conditions > 4000 chars, if so that might cause an issue but probably you can figure it out

once I did that it gave an error on a group by missing, so this new sql has r_constraint_name in the group by

```
SELECT ac.owner, ac.table_name, LISTAGG(column_name ,',' ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ac.constraint_name) AS "ABC" , ac.constraint_name, ac.constraint_type, ac.search_condition_vc,
        (SELECT ac2.table_name FROM all_cons_columns ac2 WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) fK_to_table, 
        (SELECT ac2.column_name FROM all_cons_columns ac2 WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) fK_to_column 
        FROM all_cons_columns acc, all_constraints ac WHERE     acc.constraint_name = ac.constraint_name AND acc.table_name = ac.table_name 
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'R', 'C', 'U') group by ac.owner, ac.table_name, ac.constraint_name, ac.constraint_type, ac.search_condition_vc, ac.r_constraint_name;
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed the `search_condition_vc` columns added in 12c. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm